# Re-pointing images to cloud storage

Tags: post-meta

We want to migrate our media uploads to azure blob storage.  We've copied the content across, and updated all the records in the wp_posts table so the urls all point to the new location.  Images in posts appear correctly.

There are also image references in the wp_postmeta table for records where the meta_key is _wp_attachment_metadata.  references in these records are much more complex because the references are stored as relative references with a php serialized object.  To re-point the image references, I need to add a property called "url" that points to the correct image.

**Example**

Original

```
a:5:
{
    s:5:\"width\";i:961;
    s:6:\"height\";i:618;
    s:4:\"file\";s:18:\"2017/11/myfile.png\";
    s:5:\"sizes\";a:10:
    {
        ...
    }
    s:10:\"image_meta\";a:12:
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

New:

```
a:6:
{
    s:5:\"width\";i:1300;
    s:6:\"height\";i:1219;
    s:4:\"file\";s:18:\"/2017/11/myfile.jpg\";
    s:5:\"sizes\";a:10:
    {
        ...
    }
    s:10:\"image_meta\";a:12:
    {
        ...
    }
    s:3:\"url\";s:75:\"https://mypictures.blob.core.windows.net/wpuploads-media/2017/11/myfile.jpg\";
}
```

Are there existing tools that can do this, or scripts available?  I am aware of migration plugins, but I don't think this is really a plugin question.  Normally, because the urls in the postmeta tables are all relative urls, if we migrated sites we'd have no problem, but because we're only migrating media to a different provider, and the site stays the same, we need a way to repoint existing image references.  We have an azure plugin that handles uploading to azure, and new media uploads in posts are not an issue. We just need to take care of existing references.

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic unfortunately - but if you search for database migration plugins there are multiple available.

Comment: @Sorry,  I think this is more than just a database migration thing (we are using Migrate Db Pro), because we're actually moving the media uploads to a cloud provider.  This is something the migrate plugins don't really account for.

Comment: Some migration plugins do handle media. Find one that allows you to search and replace throughout the database, while also fixing serialization errors. That way you can replace the media URLs and it will take care of serializing.

Comment: We have used one that does search and replace, but because we're migrating media to azure, the serialized objects in the postmeta tables need to change, which a search & replace can not handle.   Was hoping there were known tools or scripts I could start with.  May just have to start from scratch.  Thanks.